Using dockerize Drupal and using gitlab
Body:
I'm working on dockerizing a Drupal project, which works fine locally using the following setup:

Run composer create-project drupal/recommended-project, so that all necessary data get installed.
Use this docker-compose.yml to set up the environment:

version: '3.8'

services:
  # Drupal
  drupal:
    build:
      context: .
      target: build
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_drupal.dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8091:80'
    environment:
      DRUPAL_USER: 'HTWK'
      DRUPAL_PASSWORD: 'test'
      DRUPAL_DB_HOST: 'mariadb-drupal'
      DRUPAL_DB_PASSWORD: 'test'
    depends_on:
      - 'mariadb-drupal'
    restart: always
  
  mariadb-drupal:
    image: 'mariadb'
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MARIADB_DATABASE: 'LSN'
      MARIADB_USER: 'HTWK'
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: 'test'
    volumes:
      - '../Implementierung/Drupal/mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  phpmyadmin-drupal:
    restart: always
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin-drupal
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mariadb-drupal
    ports:
      - '8092:80'


The system works on my local machine, but I'm facing issues when pushing the setup to a GitLab repository. Once another user pulls the repository, especially on a Windows machine, the following errors occur:

"Invalid path": Some files seem to have path issues when cloned onto a Windows filesystem.
File size issues: Certain files are reported as too large to pull.

I suspect the issues might relate to how Drupal manages its files, file paths, or some kind of Git configuration.
So the main goal is that someone who pulls my branch on gitlab can start a persistent drupal container using docker compose up
I am really looking forward to any input.
